# Why does a picture of a person seem to be looking in the same direction irrespective of the angle of observation?

Tags: optics, observables

If you observe a picture of a person hanging on a wall who seems to be looking directly towards you always seems to be looking at you even though you change your angle of observation to the extremes. 
The same can be observed in a television. If a television is watched by many people from different angles all observe that a person on the screen is looking at them.

Why does it happen like that?

Update:
I First thought that it may be because of some data being lost due to conversion of 3D to 2D. But same is observed in a theater while watching a 3D movie.

Comment: I think the answer to this lies in psychology, not physics.

Comment: I disagree because it is not an assumption. It is an observation and I think observable world can be questioned under physics. And it is also not that it is observed by some and not by others. It is same observation universally. Maybe you are an exception.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about perception and artistic technique, not physics.

Comment: @MKSingh Can you add some example pictures?

Comment: I agree with your comment; I think what @joshphysics is saying is that an investigation into this repeatable and universal phenomenon would lead you to thinking about the signal processing and state evolution of the human brain. Of course this is physics, but it is as yet not amenable to analysis as a cause-begets-outcome-is-next-cause-begets-..... that physicists use. The system is simply way too complicated. So we fall back on an observation set summarised to basic, qualitative description kind of science, often backed up by statistics. This way of doing physics for a complicated system ....

Comment: ...like the human brain is what we commonly call psychology. I'm not meaning to sound like I'm telling you how to suck eggs, I guess I'm just saying this branch of physics is not what we on this site are skilled with!

Comment: I disagree with @joshphysics. This phenomenon can be equated to the broadcasting of signals from an antenna. Our eye acts as a receiving antenna. Ideally the signal does not change even when the direction is changed. In this case the signal is a 2-D image. Viewing an actual object is like receiving random signals reflected from a surface. As we change direction we receive distinct signals. Psychology also has a connection with physics. We unconsciously know the gravitational effect. When we fall from higher grounds we know that spreading arms and legs will slow us down.

Comment: This topic falls under the category of "Explanations of observed physical or astronomical phenomena". It is similar to broadcasting of signals. If antenna theory and optics are off topic then even this question is off topic.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing an object is seeing the light reflected from the surface. When we change the lighting on the object then we observe a different image.

[image]

When we observe an object from different angles we see different images. This is because the reflected light goes in different directions and we see a particular ray only in one directions. For example when a ray is reflected from side of an object, we can see the ray only when we are in the path and if we are not in the path we cannot see the side of the object.

[image: For example]

Coming to the case of a television. The image displayed on television is a 2-D image. Even if the angle of observance is change what we see is a 2-D image so we observe the same image. In case of 3-D pictures as seen in 3-D theaters we observe similar effect as in 2-D televisions. A 3-D image is formed by superimposition of multiple 2-D images of different polarization.

Answer (score 0):

A picture has only two dimensions. Ultimately all depth created through perspective and light and shadow is a trick, similarly eyes in a painting following you is also an illusion. The light, shadow and perspective depicted in a painting are fixed, meaning they don't shift. in a painting also it don't change, they look pretty much the same no matter from what angle you look at it. So if a person is painted to look at you, he or she will continue to look as you move. If a person is painted looking away from you, the light, shadow and perspective shouldn't allow him or her to ever look at you, even if you move yourself to the point where the person has been painted looking toward.